# Temporary Routes Using Meteor & Iron: Router?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, routes, iron-router

Is it possible to make a temporary route in Meteor using Iron: Router?

How it'll be applied:  When a user asks a question they will be redirected into a chatroom with a custom parameter that I supply.  When the user is done in the chatroom and leaves, I want this route to be destroyed.

ex: /chat/[custom parameter I set]

Comment: It would be helpful if you show us code that you tried. As of now, I have the following suggestion. You can use a collection to store all active chat ids. When user leaves a chat, you can remove that chat from active chats collection. Create a route using `iron-router` for /chat/:id. When a user accesses /chat/:id route you can subscribe to the active chats collection and see if the id is in the collection. If it is not there in active chats collection, then show a different template or redirect to a different url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `:` in your route to represent a value which can change but is mandatory (i.e. `/chatroom/12345` would work but `/chatroom` would not)

```
Router.route('/chatroom/:chatId', {
    name: 'chatroom',
    template: 'chatroom',
    layoutTemplate:"myLayout",
    data: function () {
        return ChatRoomData.findOne({_id:this.params.chatId});
    }
});
```

Or, you can make the parameter passed in optional by adding a `?` too

```
Router.route('/chatroom/:chatId?', {
    name: 'chatroom',
    template: 'chatroom',
    layoutTemplate:"myLayout",
    onBeforeAction: function () {
        if (!!this.params.chatId)
           //Do Something with the chatId
           this.render('specificChatRoom', {
              data: function () {
                  return ChatRoomData.findOne({_id:this.params.chatId});
              }
           });
        else
           //Do Something else
           this.render('mainChatRoom');

        this.next();
    }
});
```